# Linux: Makefile code that adds a daemon to startup scripts

Tags: linux, daemon, startup, boot

I'm currently designing a program that I want to run when my computer boots up. I've written a daemon that runs the code, so what I want is a way to run the daemon on startup. Here's my problem: I don't want to my end user to have to manually add the daemon into their list of startup scripts, I want the daemon to be added automatically when the program is installed. At the moment I have a makefile that is installing the software to my pc, so is there a way to get the makefile to insert the daemon into the user's list startup scripts, so the daemon is run on startup?

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You could have some target (perhaps `installcron`) in your `Makefile` that would use the [crontab(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/crontab.1.html) command to add (perhaps after verifying it is not there already) a [crontab(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/crontab.5.html) entry for `@reboot` (which is run at boot time).